# How to add a row into datatable on button click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, databound

In **Windows Forms**, I want to add row by row into DataGridView on button click event by taking the values from other controls. I am using DataTable in this case and it is bound to DataGridView.

I am using the following code and it is working fine when the data is inserted for the first time. But my problem is when I click the button for the second time, the first row is overwritten with the second row of data.

```
private void btnAddToGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        LoadDataGridView();
}

private void LoadDataGridView()
{
        dgvAdjustment.DataSource = GetAdjustmentTable();
}

private DataTable GetAdjustmentTable()
{
        DataTable adjustmentTable = new DataTable();

        DataColumn dataColumn;
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("SourceOutletID", typeof(int));
        adjustmentTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("DestinationOutletID", typeof(int));
        adjustmentTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("TransactionDate", typeof(DateTime));
        adjustmentTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("MaterialName", typeof(string));
        adjustmentTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("AdjustmentType", typeof(int));
        adjustmentTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("CurrentBalance", typeof(decimal));
        adjustmentTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("AdjustmentQty", typeof(decimal));
        adjustmentTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("NewBalance", typeof(decimal));
        adjustmentTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

        DataRow dataRow = adjustmentTable.NewRow();
        dataRow[0] = cmbSourceOutlet.SelectedValue;
        dataRow[1] = cmbDestinationOutlet.SelectedValue;
        dataRow[2] = TransDateTimePicker.Value;
        dataRow[3] = cmbMaterialName.SelectedValue;
        dataRow[4] = cmbAdjustmentType.SelectedValue;
        dataRow[5] = Convert.ToDecimal(lblCurBalVal.Text);
        dataRow[6] = Convert.ToDecimal(lblAdjVal.Text);
        dataRow[7] = Convert.ToDecimal(lblNewQtyVal.Text);

        int insertPosition = adjustmentTable.Rows.Count;
        adjustmentTable.Rows.InsertAt(dataRow, insertPosition);

        return adjustmentTable;
}
```

In **ASP .NET** applications, I use the session state to check whether DataTable is null by using the following code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     //Check if previous session is exist
     if (Session["MyTable"] == null)
     {
         dtMyTable = new DataTable("MyTable");
         dtMyTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
         dtMyTable.Columns.Add("LName", typeof(string));

     }
     else
     {
         //If yes then get it from current session
         dtMyTable = (DataTable)Session["MyTable"];
     }

     //Add new row every time
     DataRow dt_row;
     dt_row = dtMyTable.NewRow();
     dt_row["Id"] = TextBox1.Text;
     dt_row["LName"] = TextBox2.Text;
     dtMyTable.Rows.Add(dt_row);

     //Update session table
     Session["MyTable"] = dtMyTable;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

     Response.Write(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

What can I do and how can I make the changes to get the right solution in **Windows Forms**? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GetAdjustmentTable`, you are recreating `adjustmentTable` every time. So a new row will just overwrite the existing one.

You need to modify the code such that `adjustmentTable` is only created just once and subsequent calls add rows to it. One way to do that would be to make it a private field and to check if it's null, and create it if it is:

```
private DataTable _adjustmentTable;

private DataTable GetAdjustmentTable()
{
    if (adjustmentTable == null)
    {
        adjustmentTable = new DataTable();
    }
    ....
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! I declared DataTable outside the method and checked whether DataTable is null. Thanks for your help.